# Complex items in WebForms ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I'm currently using a ListView in my webformsapplication. This ListView generates a table with (currently) three columns. "Username", "Organization" and "Locked". These are represented with string, string and checkbox respectively. The checkbox should postback on change, but that is (possibly) for another question...

Should I use `<%# Eval("Username") %>` or `<asp:Literal blablah>` to inject the data? This is more relevant for the checkbox... It seems very "dirty" to write `<input type="checkbox" id="something" <%# if ((bool)Eval("Locked") == true) /* some unknown code for outputting "checked" */ ;%> />`

Or should I use another container alltogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checkbox, why not the asp checkbox control like:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="c" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Locked") %>' />
```

To handle the checkbox checking a little more cleanly?  I think the control would then support auto postback too on check change.

For the other question, I wouldn't worry about literals unless you need to access the value.  If you do, I would use the label personally, but any control could be used.

HTH.

Comment: Ofcource I could do this, and it's what I currently do... However, the syntax feels very dirty...

Comment: OK, looked like you had the HTML control version in your example, and why is assigning locked to a boolean dirty?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :) I changed the code inbetween my question and your answer ;). What I feel is dirty is evaluating inside an <asp> tag... But it's probably just me.